Guix: How to set one (file-system) as a dependency of another? Or mount one device before device mapping?
Say I have a LUKS partition which encrypts the root file system and whose key resides in another file system.
(mapped-devices (list
    (mapped-device
        (type (luks-device-mapping-with-options #:key-file "/early-mount/luks-key"))
        (source "/dev/sda1")
        (target "operating-system")
    )
))

How can I instruct Guix via the config.scm file to mount the second file system before the LUKS decrytion step?
Attempt #1
I tried setting (needed-for-boot? #t) on the second file system but inspecting the generated initrd script it still tries to decrypt before mounting.
(file-system
    (mount-point "/early-mount")
    (device (file-system-label "early-mount"))
    (type "ext4")
    (needed-for-boot? #t) ; This doesn't move it to #:pre-mount
)

Attempt #2
Also tried setting the root file system's dependency via (filter) and (file-system-mount-point-predicate) but I get the error:

error: file-systems: unbound variable

which makes sense because it's in the middle of defining (file-systems)
(file-systems (cons*
    (file-system ...) ; early-mount definition
    (file-system
        (mount-point "/")
        (device "/dev/mapper/operating-system")
        (type "ext4")
        (dependencies (cons*
            (filter
                (file-system-mount-point-predicate "/early-mount")
                file-systems ; This is currently being defined so it's not available yet
            )
            mapped-devices
        ))
    )
    %base-file-systems
))

Attempt #3
Tried creating a local variable via (let) for the second file system with the intention of inserting it under (file-systems) as well as under the (dependencies) but I get the error:

error: (let ...): invalid field specifier

(let
    (
        (early-mount
            (file-system
                (mount-point "/early-mount")
                (device (file-system-label "early-mount"))
                (type "ext4")
                (needed-for-boot? #t)
            )
        )
    )
    (file-systems (cons*
        early-mount
        (file-system
            (mount-point "/")
            (device "/dev/mapper/operating-system")
            (type "ext4")
            (dependencies (cons*
                early-mount
                mapped-devices
            ))
        )
        %base-file-systems
    ))
)

Attempt #4
Then tried repeating the second file system (file-system) entry and this actually allows me to deploy the config:
(file-systems (cons*
    (file-system ...) ; early-mount definition
    (file-system
        (mount-point "/")
        (device "/dev/mapper/operating-system")
        (type "ext4")
        (dependencies (cons*
            (file-system ...) ; early-mount definition, copy/pasted
            mapped-devices
        ))
    )
    %base-file-systems
))

however this tries to prompts me for the password during boot, leading me to believe that it wasn't able to mount /early-mount before trying to do the LUKS open.

In order to mount a file system before device mapping takes place (for example when you need a key on a USB drive to decrypt a LUKS partition), use the raw-initrd procedure within the (initrd) field of (operating-system) and add the mount in the #:pre-mount parameter like so:
(operating-system

    ;...

    (mapped-devices ...) ; As normal

    (file-systems ...) ; With or without the file system to 'pre-mount'

    (initrd
        (lambda*
            (
                file-systems
                #:key
                    (linux-modules '())
                    (keyboard-layout #f)
                    (helper-packages '())
                    volatile-root?
                    #:allow-other-keys
                ; Will always include all keys. Call raw-initrd with this first then override.
                #:rest all-key-arguments
            )

            (apply
                raw-initrd
                (append
                    (list file-systems)
                    all-key-arguments
                    (list
                        ; TODO https://issues.guix.gnu.org/74285
                        ;#:linux-modules linux-modules 
                        #:pre-mount
                            #~(begin
                                (use-modules (
                                    (gnu build file-systems)
                                        #:select (mount-file-system)
                                ))
                                (mount-file-system
                                    (file-system
                                        (mount-point "/mnt/my-label")
                                        (device (file-system-label "my-label"))
                                        (type "ext4")
                                    )
                                    ; This is needed otherwise the mount point
                                    ;  will be prefixed by '/root'
                                    #:root ""
                                )
                            )
                        #:helper-packages (append
                            helper-packages
                            (file-system-packages
                                file-systems
                                #:volatile-root? volatile-root?
                            )
                            (if keyboard-layout
                                (list loadkeys-static)
                                '()
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)

